# A sugary coup: what's the meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading an american novel, written last year. A woman is talking about a patisserie which is very popupular between teenagers; she says:

> Its cakes were so popular that locations were popping up across the city, **a sugary coup.**

Does it mean that store were opening across the city? And what's the meaning of "a sugary coup"? Given the context, it may be ironical, but I don't understand the exact meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "coup" is short for "coup d'état", which the [learners dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/coup%20d%27%C3%A9tat) defines as

> a sudden attempt by a small group of people to take over the government usually through violence

The word "coup" is also used to mean generally taking over.

In this case, the context is a cake is becoming popular. So the sentence is saying that it's a *sugary coup* - a cake has sugar in it, and is generally pretty sweet, and the cakes (or the store that's selling them) is quickly expanding and creating new stores, so it can appear as if they're taking over.

Long story short, it means that this sweet treat is becoming so popular that it's as if it's taking over.

Comment: Mostly agreed, but I wouldn't say it's "short for *coup d'état*", since *coup* just means "a blow" or "a stroke", and we use *coup* in other phrases too (like *coup de grâce*).